# Java getResourceAsStream static workaround. Correct?

Tags: java, static, resources

I was using this code to get my resources:

```
 this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("Image.png");
```

it worked fine up until the point where I had to implement it in a static method:

```
 public class UserDisplay {

 public static void PlayerWon(final Display display, String player, final Composite WinCompo){
```

I could not use the `this` keyword in static context so I used the object I previously initialized:

```
public class UserDisplay {

 public static void PlayerWon(final Display display, String player, final Composite WinCompo){

    final AudioLoop WinLoop = new AudioLoop("Sound.wav");

    final Image WinBanner = new Image(display, WinLoop.getClass().getResourceAsStream("Image.png"));
```

It works fine, but here is my Question:

Is this a legitimate workaround? If not, what should I have done?

Note: I apologize for the poor Title.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a [class literal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.2) instead. It's not clear what `AudioLoop` is in this case, but unless it's a class in your own library, that's probably *not* what you want. I suspect you want something like:

```
new Image(display, UserDisplay.class.getResourceAsStream("Image.png"))
```

If you *do* want to get a resource relative to the `AudioLoop` class, use:

```
new Image(display, AudioLoop.class.getResourceAsStream("Image.png"))
```

Also note that your method and variable names don't currently comply with Java naming conventions, where both would normally be `camelCased`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Yes, AudioLoop is an Object I created.       I changed it to UserDisplay.class. That is what I wanted to do, but I was unsure how to do it. I will take not of the Java naming conventions next time I am coding. Thank you.

Comment: Would you mind up-voting my post? I am new and trying to gain reputation. What would you suggest to help increase my reputation?

Comment: @JayCodeBuilder: You can always look for helpful edits to make to posts, but answering questions is the best way of getting rep IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Use the UserDisplay.class.getResourceAsStream("Image.png"). You are getting a reference to the same class just in a different way.

Comment: Thank you, I realized it would create a reference to the same class, that is why I coded it that way. I have changed it to the way you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Getting from class and don't forget a class loader:

```
new Image(display, 
  UserDisplay.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Image.png"))
```